# How to avoid series hiding yAxis using JSCharting

Tags: javascript, charts, deployment, chart.js, jscharts

I am using JSCharting to create a chart with vertical bars. I have a vertical y-axis in the chart, but the bars are partially hiding this axis, making it difficult to see. I would like to find a solution to prevent the series from hiding the y-axis.

[what the graph looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovPno.png)

And this is the code I have

```
yAxis: {
    markers: [
        {
            value: fechaActual,
            color: '#b0be5f',
            label_text: 'Fecha actual'
        }
    ]
},
defaultSeries: {
    defaultPoint: {
        legendEntry: {
            value: '{days(%max-%min):number n0} days'
        },
        tooltip: '<b>%name</b> <br/>%low - %high<br/>{days(%high-%low)} días',
        marker_type: 'diamond'
    },
    firstPoint: {
        xAxisTick: {label: {text: '<b>%name</b>', style: {fontSize: '14px'}}},
        outline: {color: 'darkenMore', width: 3}
    }
}
```

As you see the vertical line Fecha Actual is hidden by the series

Comment: In the image you attached it's not the y axis that is partially covered, it the *legend*. With that you may start working/experimenting with the multiple [legend configuration options](https://jscharting.com/documentation/#node=Home.API.json.Types.legend) to make it fully visible

Comment: @kikon so what parameter do I have to use?

Comment: I'm not sure; depends on how you want it to look. You may try `legend:{layout: 'horizontal'}` or `legend:{defaultEntry:{ height: 10,  style:{fontSize: 6}}}` (choose your values). If you posted the full example with data, possibly as a jsCharting editor link, we could experiment ourselves and propose different variants...